# How to generate PDF report from a JSP page?

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsp, pdf

I cannot seem to generate the PDF report from this JSP page. Although I'm able to generate the form in a .pdf format, but it fails to open in Adobe Reader.

```
<%

//response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
//response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
//response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Donation Report.pdf");
%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>certificateword</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
     <style> 
.crtf_div{width:900px; height:auto; text-align:center; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border:1px solid #000; padding:25px 0px;}
.crtf_div p{width:850px; height:auto; margin:20px 25px; text-align:justify; font-size:14px;}
.crtf_head{width:900px; height:auto; text-align:center; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;}
.crtf_head .head_small{font-size:12px;}

.crtf_table{width:850px; height:auto; margin:10px 25px; border:1px solid #000; text-align:left; font-size:14px;}
.crtf_table tr td input{width:670px; height:20px; border:0px;}
.crtf_table tr td textarea{width:670px; height:50px; border:0px;}0


.crtf_list{width:auto; height:auto; margin:10px 25px; text-align:justify; font-size:14px;}
.crtf_list ol li{width:auto; height:auto; margin-bottom:10px;}
</style>
 <center>
  <div class="crtf_div">
<Div class="crtf_head">Office of the <br />
Director of Income Tax (E),<br />
3rd Floor, Aaykar Bhawan,<br />
District Centre Laxmi Nagar, Delhi - 110092<br />
<div class="head_small">Tel. No. 011-2055545, 22054777</div>
</Div>
<br />

<table class="crtf_table" style="border:0px; text-align:center;">
<tr>
    <td>NQ.DIT (E) I 2013-14/</td>
    <td>DEL - XXXXXXX XXXXXXXX</td>
    <td>Dated &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 05/05/2014</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="crtf_table" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
  <td width="150">NAME</td>
  <td ><input type="text" name="name" value=" "/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>ADDRESS</td>
  <td><textarea name="add" rows="4" cols="20" value=" "></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Legal Status</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lstatus" value="----"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>PAN NO. </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pan" value="XXXXX"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>GIR NO.</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gir" value="XXXX-XXXX"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p><b>Sub :- ORDER UNDER SECTION 80G (5)(vi) OF THE INCOME TAX ACT, 1961</b></p>
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; On verification of the facts stated before me/hearing before me, I have come to the conclusion that this organization satisfies the conditions u/s 80G of .the Income Tax act, 1961. The institution/Fund is granted approval subject to the following conditions--</p>

<div class="crtf_list">
    <ol type="i">
    <li>The Donee institution shall forfeit this benefit provided under the law, if any of the conditions stated herein is not 
    complied with/abused/whittled down or in any way violated.</li>
    <li>This exemption is valid for the period from A.Y.2013-14 onwards till it is rescinded    and subject to the following conditions</li>
</ol>
</div>

<p><b>Conditions:</b></p>

<div class="crtf_list">
<ol type="i">
    <li>You shall maintain your accounts regularly and also get them audited to comply with sec. 80G (5)(iv) read with section 12A(b) 
    and 12A(c) and submit the same before the assessing officer by the due date as per section 139-(t) of the Income tax Act 1961.</li>
    <li> Every receipt issued to donor shall bear the number and date; of this order and shall state the date up to which this 
    certificate is valid from   A.Y.2013-14 onwards till it is rescinded.</li>
    <li> No change in the deed of the trust/association shall be affected without the due procedure of Law and its intimation 
    shall be given immediately to this office.</li>
    <li> The approval to the institution/fund shall aroply to the donations received only if the fund/institution, established 
    in India for charitable purpose, fulfills the conditions as laid down in section 80G(i), (ii), (iii), (iv) & (v) of the Income Tax Act 1961.</li>
    <li> This office and the assessing officer shall also be informed about the managing trustees or Manager of your Trust/Society/Non Profit 
    Company and the places where the activities of the Trust/Institution are undertaken/likely to be undertaken to satisfy the claimed objects.</li>
    <li> You shall file the return of income of liour fund/institution as per section  139(1)/(4A)/(4C) of the Income Tax Act.</li>
</ol>
</div>
<br /><br />

 <table class="crtf_table" style="border:0px; line-height:20px;">
<tr>
    <td><b>Copy to:</b><br />
    1. The applicant as above<br />
    2. The Assessing Officer
    </td>
    <td style="float:right; text-align:center;"><br />
    Director of Income Tax (Exemption)<br />
    DELHI<br /><br /><br />
    <br />
    Income Tax Officer (Exemption) (Hqrs.)<br />
    For Director of Income Tax (Exemption) DELHI
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
 <p>As it is a computer generated letter, No signature is required</p>

 </div>
 </center><br><br>

</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: *i'm able to generate the form in a .pdf format* - No, you are not, at least not in the code you posted. Here you generate the form in HTML tag it as PDF. Naming your nose "beard" doesn't make it a beard.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix two mimetypes on the page like you're trying to do.

Take all the HTML out.  After these two lines

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Donation Report.pdf");
```

All that should be done is you should print out the bytes of the PDF file.  And you probably will have to do this in a servlet, since in JSP attempting to do this often gets the error that response.getOutputStream() has already been called.

And the line

```
response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Donation Report.pdf");
```

Does nothing but tell the browser the filename of what you are about to print after this. It doesn't go and fetch the PDF itself.  You have to open the PDF, read it into a byte array, and print it to response.getOutputStream()